# Is pointwise convergence useful?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

The properties such as boundedness, continuity, integrability require uniform convergence of sequence of functions.

I wonder, is there any property that pointwise convergence manages to transfer to limit function? Or is it completely useless?

Comment: measurability I would say.

Comment: @drhab, why do add this as a comment, not an answer?

Comment: Stimulated by you I have made it an answer now. The "real-analysis" tag made me suspect that you are busy on the side of Riemann (measurability "belongs more" to Lebesgue). I might be wrong of course.

Comment: @drhab, thanks. Actually, I'm aware of what measurable function means, so it's good example.

Comment: In the context of Lebesgue integration, sometimes pointwise convergence + additional hypothesis allows us to switch integrals and limits (so we don't always need uniform convergence). For example, see [Dominated Convergence Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If functions $f_n$ are measurable and converge pointwise to a limitfunction $f$ then also function $f$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

no. $f_n(x)$ is some sequence and check definitions of those two types of convergence, in uniform you have $\exists n_0 \forall x $ and in pointvise $\exists x \forall n_0$  that mean uniform $\implies $ pointwise, and is not that useless. good thing about pointwise covergence is that it is easier to chack then uniform, so if you check is fome sequence converge uniformly you usualy first check pointwise and get limit. if it converge uniformly it has same limit as pointwise, and you check uniform convergence by definition. you cant always guess limit and do uniform by definition. also if it does not converge pointwise it does not converge uniformly, so no checking for uniform convergence if you know it will not converge. when (if) you start doing examples you will see what i was talking about

Comment: I expected that an answer would provide an example of a property of a function that is preserved under pointwise convergence.

Comment: limit is preserved, if there is one

Comment: Let me rephrase: if each function $f_n$ has property P and $f_n \rightarrow f$, then f has property P. The "limit" isn't such P.

Comment: oh that , sorry i did not understand question, then nothing, it is useless in that sense. only what i whote above.